# Get image link and text from string

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have this string

```
<div><img width="100px" src="http://www.mysite.com/Content/dataImages/news/small/some-pic.png" /><br />This is some text that I need to get.</div>
```

and i need to get the image link and the text `This is some text that I need to get.`from the string above in Java. Can anybody tell me how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Since your atring is HTML code... Give a look at [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Or jSoup. It lets you access content from HTML with a selection system that mirrors CSS selectors

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all you have to do there's no point in bringing in extra packages just use regex:
The pattern "(?<=src=\")(.*?)(?=\")" can be used to get the link, you can modify that to give you the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just change the patter if you must.

```
String str = "<div><img width=\"100px\" src=\"http://www.mysite.com/Content/dataImages/news/small/some-pic.png\" /><br />This is some text that I need to get.</div>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\" /><br />(.*?)</div>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String link = m.group(1);
    String text = m.group(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

```
String tmp=xpp.nextText();
desc=android.text.Html.fromHtml(tmp).toString();
img=FindUrls.extractUrls(tmp);
```

for extracting the text from the string I used:

```
desc=android.text.Html.fromHtml(tmp).toString();
img=FindUrls.extractUrls(tmp);
```

and for the link inside the string I've used this function:

```
 public static String extractUrls(String input) {

        String result = null;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
            "\\b(((ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/|~\\/|\\/)|www.)" + 
            "(\\w+:\\w+@)?(([-\\w]+\\.)+(com|org|net|gov" + 
            "|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum" + 
            "|travel|[a-z]{2}))(:[\\d]{1,5})?" + 
            "(((\\/([-\\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})+)+|\\/)+|\\?|#)?" + 
            "((\\?([-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" + 
            "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)" + 
            "(&(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" + 
            "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)*)*" + 
            "(#([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)?\\b");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            result=matcher.group();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Hope It will help someone that has similar problem